# Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = L$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = L$.

If $L > 0$,

We want to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$,

while if $L < 0$,

we want to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = -\infty$.

I am using the definition for what we want to show (e.g. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$) as:

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined on $(0, \infty).$  Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ if for every number $N > 0$ there is some number $M > 0$ such that $$f(x) > N \quad \text{whenever}\quad x > M$$
and 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ if for every number $N < 0$ there is some number $M > 0$ such that $$f(x) < N \quad \text{whenever}\quad x > M.$$

Now by the hypothesis, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = L$, so given $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $M > 0$ such that $x > M$ implies $|f'(x) - L| <\epsilon$.

Now my problem is connecting this expression involving $f'(x)$ to $f(x)$. Can I get some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $M>0$ such that $x>M$ implies $f'(x)>\frac{L}{2}$. If $x>M$, then by the mean value theorem there exists some $x<y<M$ such that:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(M)}{x-M}=f'(y)\Longrightarrow f(x)>(x-M)\frac{L}{2}+f(M)$$

As this inequality holds for every $x>M$, one deduces that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

The second assertion follows from the first by looking at $-f(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by looking at $-f(x)$?

Comment: I mean that if you are given that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L$ and $L<0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(-f'(x))=-L$ and $-L>0$, so from the first part that we proved we deduce that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(-f(x))=\infty$, hence $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.